# Fetching results with a list of CKQuery

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckquery

I have a CKRecord of recipes that gets fetched to an iOS app. Once I have that list, I need to prioritize the results of recipes that are the highest suggested "likedIds" which is a list of integers representing recipe_ids (please see my dataset image below), then display the remaining recipes below that. I can't merely sort by highest rated recipes because I'm using collaborative filtering elsewhere in the project to suggest specific recipes over others, but I still want to list them all.

Here in this code below I am appending the results of `NSPredicates` to a list of `CKQuery` called 'queries'. Now that I have that `[CKquery]`, what do I do with it? How do I fetch the results I need? Which method do I use, if `publicDB.perform()` isn't the right method (since I get an 'expected argument type' error)? Below, I tried using a for loop inside of the `AttachToMainThread()` function that I wrote, but I get 3 different random results at refresh, recipes in the "likedIds" list, recipes not the "likedIds" list, or nothing at all, yet no SIGABRT errors which is nice.

##### TL;DR

What do I do with my `CKquery` list to fetch results?

Thank you for your time!

### Just the code focusing on the primary subject:

```
import Foundation
import CloudKit

class Model {
  // MARK: - iCloud Info
  let container: CKContainer
  let publicDB: CKDatabase

  private(set) var recipes: [Recipe] = []
  static var currentModel = Model()
  
  init() {
    container = CKContainer.default()
    publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
  }
  
  @objc func refresh(_ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    var queries = [CKQuery] () 
    // Function that returns a CKQuery
    let likedQuery = GetRecipesWithLikedIds()
    queries.append(likedQuery)
    
    // Function that returns a CKQuery
    let unlikedQuery = GetRecipesWithoutLikedIds()
    queries.append(unlikedQuery)

    AttachToMainThread(forQuery: queries, completion)
  }

  private func AttachToMainThread(forQuery queries: [CKQuery],
      _ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    for q in queries {
      publicDB.perform(q,
          inZoneWith: CKRecordZone.default().zoneID) { [weak self] results, error in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        if let error = error {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(error)
          }
          return
        }
        guard let results = results else { return }
        self.recipes = results.compactMap {
          Recipe(record: $0, database: self.publicDB)
          
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(nil)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### My entire code:

```
    import Foundation
    import CloudKit
    
    class Model {
      // MARK: - iCloud Info
      let container: CKContainer
      let publicDB: CKDatabase
      
      var carbohydrate = "rice"
      var vegetable = "tomatoes"
      
      // MARK: - Properties
      private(set) var recipes: [Recipe] = []
    
      static var currentModel = Model()
      
      init() {
        container = CKContainer.default()
        publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
        privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
      }
      
      @objc func refresh(_ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        var queries = [CKQuery] ()
        
        let likedQuery = GetRecipesWithLikedIds()
        queries.append(likedQuery)
        let unlikedQuery = GetRecipesWithoutLikedIds()
        queries.append(unlikedQuery)
    
        AttachToMainThread(forQuery: queries, completion)
      }
    
      private func AttachToMainThread(forQuery queries: [CKQuery],
          _ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        for q in queries {
          publicDB.perform(q,
              inZoneWith: CKRecordZone.default().zoneID) { [weak self] results, error in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if let error = error {
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(error)
              }
              return
            }
            guard let results = results else { return }
            self.recipes = results.compactMap {
              Recipe(record: $0, database: self.publicDB)
              
            }
            for r in self.recipes {
              self.PrettyPrintRecipes(rName: r.name, rId: String(r.recipe_id), rIng: r.ingredients)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              completion(nil)
            }
          }
        }
      }
      
      func GetRecipesWithLikedIds() -> CKQuery {
        let searchTextA: [String] = [carbohydrate," "+carbohydrate,carbohydrate+"s",carbohydrate+"es"]
        let subPred1 = NSPredicate (format: "ANY ingredients IN %@",argumentArray: [searchTextA])
        let searchTextB: [String] = [vegetable," "+vegetable,vegetable+"s",vegetable+"es"]
        let subPred2 = NSPredicate (format: "ANY ingredients IN %@",argumentArray: [searchTextB])
        let likedIds: [Int] = [13733,32441]
        let subPred3 = NSPredicate (format: "NOT (recipe_id IN %@)", likedIds)
        let and_pred1 = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [subPred1, subPred2])
        let and_pred2 = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [subPred3])
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [and_pred1, and_pred2])
        return CKQuery(recordType: "Recipe", predicate: predicate)
      }
      
      func GetRecipesWithoutLikedIds() -> CKQuery {
        let searchTextA: [String] = [carbohydrate," "+carbohydrate,carbohydrate+"s",carbohydrate+"es"]
        let subPred1 = NSPredicate (format: "ANY ingredients IN %@",argumentArray: [searchTextA])
        let searchTextB: [String] = [vegetable," "+vegetable,vegetable+"s",vegetable+"es"]
        let subPred2 = NSPredicate (format: "ANY ingredients IN %@",argumentArray: [searchTextB])
        let likedIds: [Int] = [13733,32441]
        let subPred3 = NSPredicate (format: "recipe_id IN %@",argumentArray: [likedIds])
        let and_pred1 = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [subPred1, subPred2])
        let and_pred2 = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [subPred3])
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [and_pred1, and_pred2])
        return CKQuery(recordType: "Recipe", predicate: predicate)
      }
    
      func PrettyPrintRecipes(rName: String, rId: String, rIng: [String]) {
        print("Name: "+rName)
        print("Recipe_id: "+rId)
        print("Ingredients:")
        for s in 0..<rIng.count {
          print("\t"+String(s)+": "+rIng[s])
        }
      }
      
      public func printVegetable(){
        print(vegetable)
      }
    }
```

### An Example Image of my Dataset

[image: Example image from my recipes CKRecord]

Comment: 'carbohydrate'?  'vegetable'?  'likedIds'?  Nobody even knows anything about your dataset.

Comment: Hey @ElTomato, I really appreciate your helpfulness in pointing out areas in which my post can be improved. With your assistance, I added more to my post to guide those who are unfamiliar with my specific situation.

Comment: @ElTomato can you please show me an example of what to do with a list of CKQuery? Preferably in Swift.